# Calling a jar with multiple main methods in batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

I have created one jar with four modules in it that means I have four main classes in that jar.
Now, I need to call this jar in a batch file according to module calling to perform some action.

Answer (score 4):

You can call class from a jar using the following command :

```
java -cp theJar.jar mypackage.MyClass
```

Answer (score 2):

Per JAR spec, there can only be one `Main-Class` defined in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file.

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Main_Attributes